# Preventing template arguments implicit conversion

Tags: c++, templates

If I have this code:

```
std::pair<Class1*,std::string> myFunc()
{
  ... 
  return std::make_pair(m_myptr, m_mystr);
}
```

how do I enforce returning a std::pair with a pointer to Class1 and a std::string? I don't want any implicit conversion taking place. Since template arguments are deduced here, how do I enforce that?

Simply expliciting parameters with

```
return std::make_pair<Class1*,std::string>(m_myptr, m_mystr);
```

is throwing an error with VS2012

Comment: What error? How are `m_myptr` and `m_mystr` declared?

Comment: Yes they are, but for some reason this is the error :

Error: 'std::make_pair' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Class1 *' to 'Class1 *&&'

Comment: uhm... just found.. http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/691756/std

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only purpose for `make_pair` is to deduce the types of the template parameters for `pair`. If you already know exactly the type of `pair` you want, initialize it directly instead of calling `make_pair`:

```
return std::pair<Class1*,std::string>(m_myptr, m_mystr);
```

or (C++11):

```
return {m_myptr, m_mystr};
```

Comment: Can a pointer like Class2* be cast to Class1* ? Is that allowed?

Comment: @DavidKernin only if Class2 inherits from Class1

Comment: @DavidKernin You want to forbid implicit conversions of `m_myptr` and `m_mystr`? I understood the question to mean that you wanted to forbid conversion of the return value from some other `pair` type to `pair<Class1*,std::string>`.